# Call to undefined function flag_get_flag() with Flag 4.x

Tags: nodes, flags

I'm using the 8.x-4.0-beta3 release of the [Flag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) in a custom D9 module to flag a newly programmatically created node using a flag I created in the UI.

```
$flag = flag_get_flag('new_call');
$flag->flag('flag', $call_node->nid);
$call_node->save();
```

But this results in this error when it is called:

```
Error: Call to undefined function Drupal\zoom_call\flag_get_flag() in Drupal\zoom_call\ZoomApiWebhookEventSubscriber->clientcall() (line 75 of /var/www/html/modules/zoom_call/src/ZoomApiWebhookEventSubscriber.php)
```

Does someone know a solution to this? Is flag_get_flag() deprecated in D9 perhaps?

Comment: Try \flag_get_flag

Comment: @cilefen Gives the same undefined function error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the flag service:

```
$flag_id = 'bookmark';

$flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
$flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);

// Flag an entity with a specific flag.
$flag_service->flag($flag, $entity);

// Unflag an entity with a specific flag.
$flag_service->unflag($flag, $entity);
```

Documentation for Flag 4.x is lacking but I made a [list of the basics](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag/issues/3157623).

Comment: That works, thank you, for both the solution and list.